# Need to create option for km or mi using Tkinter and Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, geopy

So below I have a code that I found and modified for calculating the distance between two locations. I am creating a GUI for simple user input. Everything is working as expected but it would be a bonus if I could accomplish two things.

1. Have a toggle or selection that would allow me to show the distance in either KM or Mi
2. is there any way that I could round the output so it doesn't have so many digits after the decimal?

I assume it has to be some type of a variable based on the object selection?

> ```
> # import modules 
> from tkinter import *
> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim 
> from geopy import distance 
>
> # user defined funtion 
> def get_dis(): 
>   try: 
>       
>       geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises") 
>       
>       place1 = geolocator.geocode(str(e1.get())) 
>       place2 = geolocator.geocode(str(e2.get())) 
>
>
>       Loc1_lat,Loc1_lon = (place1.latitude),(place1.longitude) 
>       Loc2_lat,Loc2_lon = (place2.latitude),(place2.longitude) 
>
>       location1=(Loc1_lat,Loc1_lon) 
>       location2=(Loc2_lat,Loc2_lon) 
>
>       res = (str(distance.distance(location1, location2).mi)+" Mi") 
>
>       result.set(res) 
>   except: 
>       result.set("someting went wrong") 
>
> # object of tkinter 
> # with background set to light grey 
> master = Tk() 
> master.configure(bg='light grey') 
> master.title("Find Distance") 
>
> # Variable Classes in tkinter 
> result = StringVar(); 
>
>
> # Creating label for each information 
> # name using widget Label 
> Label(master, text="Start Location : " , bg = "light grey").grid(row=1, sticky=W) 
> Label(master, text="End Location : " , bg = "light grey").grid(row=2, sticky=W) 
>
> Label(master, text="Result :", bg = "light grey").grid(row=3, sticky=W) 
>
> # Creating label for class variable 
> # name using widget Entry 
> Label(master, text="", textvariable=result,bg = "light grey").grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W) 
>
>
> e1 = Entry(master,width = 50) 
> e1.grid(row=1, column=1) 
> e2 = Entry(master,width = 50) 
> e2.grid(row=2, column=1) 
>
> # creating a button using the widget 
> b = Button(master, text="Check", command=get_dis, bg = "white") 
> b.grid(row=1, column=2,columnspan=2, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=5,) 
>
> mainloop()
> ```

edit with notes.. cant get to round

> ## import modules  from tkinter import * from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim  from geopy import distance
>
> ## user defined funtion  def get_dis():
>
> ```
> try: 
>       
>     geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises") 
>       
>     place1 = geolocator.geocode(str(e1.get())) 
>     place2 = geolocator.geocode(str(e2.get())) 
>
>
>     Loc1_lat,Loc1_lon = (place1.latitude),(place1.longitude) 
>     Loc2_lat,Loc2_lon = (place2.latitude),(place2.longitude) 
>
>     location1=(Loc1_lat,Loc1_lon) 
>     location2=(Loc2_lat,Loc2_lon) 
>
>     res = (str(distance.distance(location1, location2) .km)+" Km") 
>
>     result.set(res) 
> except: 
>     result.set("someting went wrong") 
>
> def get_dis():
>
>     if unit.get() == 'mi':
>         res = str(round(distance.distance(location1, location2).mi, 2))+" Mi"
>     else:
>         res = str(round(distance.distance(location1, location2).km, 2))+" km"
> ```
>
> ## object of tkinter
>
> ## with background set to light grey  master = Tk()  master.configure(bg='light grey')  master.title("Find Distance")
>
> ## Variable Classes in tkinter  result = StringVar();  Label(master, text="", textvariable=result,bg = "light grey").grid(row=4,column=1,
>
> sticky=W)
>
> ## Creating label for each information
>
> ## name using widget Label   Label(master, text="Start Location : " , bg = "light grey").grid(row=1, sticky=W)  Label(master, text="End
>
> Location : " , bg = "light grey").grid(row=2, sticky=W)
> Label(master, text="Distance :", bg = "light grey").grid(row=3,
> sticky=W)
>
> ## Creating label for class variable
>
> ## name using widget Entry  Label(master, text="Unit :", bg="light gray").grid(row=3, sticky=W) Label(master, text="Result :", bg =
>
> "light grey").grid(row=4, sticky=W)
> e1 = Entry(master,width = 50)  e1.grid(row=1, column=1)  e2 = Entry(master,width = 50)  e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
>
> f1 = Frame(master) f1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W) unit =
> StringVar(value="mi") Radiobutton(f1, text="miles", value="mi",
> variable=unit, bg="light gray").pack(side="left") Radiobutton(f1,
> text="km", value="km", variable=unit, bg="light
> gray").pack(side="left")
>
> ## creating a button using the widget    b = Button(master, text="Calculate", command=get_dis, bg = "white")  b.grid(row=1,
>
> column=2,columnspan=2, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=5,)     mainloop()

Comment: Please provide proper formatting in your questions. This formatting is extremely impractical and hard to read, so much so that we can't fix it. We can't tell whether some of those bold lines were intended to be comments in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add two radiobuttons before result row:

```
Label(master, text="Unit :", bg="light gray").grid(row=3, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="Result :", bg = "light grey").grid(row=4, sticky=W) # changed to row 4
...
f1 = Frame(master)
f1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
unit = StringVar(value="mi")
Radiobutton(f1, text="miles", value="mi", variable=unit, bg="light gray").pack(side="left")
Radiobutton(f1, text="km", value="km", variable=unit, bg="light gray").pack(side="left")

result = StringVar(); 
Label(master, text="", textvariable=result,bg = "light grey").grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W) # changed to row 4
```

Then call the corresponding function based on the unit selected inside `get_dis()`:

```
def get_dis():
    try:
        ...
        if unit.get() == 'mi':
            res = str(round(distance.distance(location1, location2).mi, 3))+" Mi"
        else:
            res = str(round(distance.distance(location1, location2).km, 3))+" km"
    ...
```

Note that `round(..., 3)` is used to round the result to have 3 digits after the decimal.

Comment: thanks, I think I got everything working other then the rounding.. doesn't seem to want to round at all

Comment: added what I updated above if you could take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
# import modules 
from tkinter import *
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim 
from geopy import distance 
  
# user defined funtion 
def get_dis(): 
     
          
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises") 
        
    place1 = geolocator.geocode(str(e1.get())) 
    place2 = geolocator.geocode(str(e2.get())) 


    Loc1_lat,Loc1_lon = (place1.latitude),(place1.longitude) 
    Loc2_lat,Loc2_lon = (place2.latitude),(place2.longitude) 

    location1=(Loc1_lat,Loc1_lon) 
    location2=(Loc2_lat,Loc2_lon) 

    res = (str(distance.distance(location1, location2) .km)+" Km") 

    if unit.get() == 'mi':
        res = str(round(distance.distance(location1, location2).mi, 2))+" Mi"
    else:
        res = str(round(distance.distance(location1, location2).km, 2))+" km"

    result.set(res) 
  
# object of tkinter 
# with background set to light grey 
master = Tk() 
master.configure(bg='light grey') 
master.title("Find Distance") 
  
# Variable Classes in tkinter 
result = StringVar(); 
Label(master, text="", textvariable=result,bg = "light grey").grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W)  
  
# Creating label for each information 
# name using widget Label  
Label(master, text="Start Location : " , bg = "light grey").grid(row=1, sticky=W) 
Label(master, text="End Location : " , bg = "light grey").grid(row=2, sticky=W) 
  
  
# Creating label for class variable 
# name using widget Entry 
Label(master, text="Unit :", bg="light gray").grid(row=3, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="Result :", bg = "light grey").grid(row=4, sticky=W) 
  
  
e1 = Entry(master,width = 50) 
e1.grid(row=1, column=1) 
e2 = Entry(master,width = 50) 
e2.grid(row=2, column=1) 

f1 = Frame(master)
f1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
unit = StringVar(value="mi")
Radiobutton(f1, text="miles", value="mi", variable=unit, bg="light gray").pack(side="left")
Radiobutton(f1, text="km", value="km", variable=unit, bg="light gray").pack(side="left")

# creating a button using the widget   
b = Button(master, text="Calculate", command=get_dis, bg = "white") 
b.grid(row=1, column=2,columnspan=2, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=5,) 
  
mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Since we are already getting the distance in one of the units with the `check` button..let's use that. We will convert it's result to the other. Changed `Check` to `Distance in miles`, Added a new button for `KM`. Create a function to convert miles to km. Then a function to call both functions.`Two`. This will get distance in miles(`get_dis`) and convert to KM(`km_mi`). The result will have no decimals. I used `int`. If you want decimals you can use `round` as suggested in the other answer.

```
from tkinter import *
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy import distance


# user defined function
def get_dis():
    try:
        global res
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")

        place1 = geolocator.geocode(str(e1.get()))
        place2 = geolocator.geocode(str(e2.get()))

        Loc1_lat, Loc1_lon = (place1.latitude), (place1.longitude)
        Loc2_lat, Loc2_lon = (place2.latitude), (place2.longitude)

        location1 = (Loc1_lat, Loc1_lon)
        location2 = (Loc2_lat, Loc2_lon)
        res = int(distance.distance(location1, location2).mi)
        return result.set(res)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def km_mki():
    miles = res
    conv_fac = 1.609  # conversion factor
    # calculating how many kilometers
    kilometers = miles * conv_fac
    return result.set(int(kilometers))
def two():
    get_dis()
    km_mki()


# object of tkinter
# with background set to light grey
master = Tk()
master.configure(bg='light grey')
master.title("Find Distance")

# Variable Classes in tkinter
result = StringVar()

# Creating label for each information
# name using widget Label
Label(master, text="Start Location : ", bg="light grey").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="End Location : ", bg="light grey").grid(row=2, sticky=W)

Label(master, text="Result :", bg="light grey").grid(row=3, sticky=W)

# Creating label for class variable
# name using widget Entry
Label(master, text="", textvariable=result, bg="light grey").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

e1 = Entry(master, width=50)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
e2 = Entry(master, width=50)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1)

# creating a button using the widget
b = Button(master, text="Get distance in Miles", command=get_dis, bg="white")
b.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, )
b1 = Button(master, text="Get distance in Km", command=two, bg="white")
b1.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, )

mainloop()
```

Comment: Request users to copy paste my code and please let me know what is wrong with the answer. thanks.